# SWI-Prolog Puzzle

Tags: prolog, puzzle

This is the problem :

> Victor has been murdered, and Arthur, Bertram, and Carleton are
>   suspects. Arthur says he did not do it. He says that Bertram was the
>   victim’s friend but that Carleton hated the victim. Bertram says he
>   was out of town the day of the murder, and besides he didn’t even know
>   the guy. Carleton says he is innocent and he saw Arthur and Bertram
>   with the victim just before the murder. Assuming that everyone–except
>   possibly for the murderer–is telling the truth, use resolution to
>   solve the crime.

This is what I wrote in SWI Prolog

```
% Facts:
p('Arthur').    % suspect
p('Bertram').   % suspect
p('Carleton').  % suspect
p('Victor').    % victim
% Arthur
says('Arthur', i('Arthur')).
says('Arthur', f('Bertram', 'Victor')).
says('Arthur', ht('Carleton', 'Victor')).
% Bertram
says('Bertram', o('Bertram')).
says('Bertram', nk('Bertram', 'Victor')).
% Carleton
says('Carleton', i('Carleton')).
says('Carleton', t('Arthur', 'Victor')).
says('Carleton', t('Bertram', 'Victor')).
% Rules:
holds(X) :- says(Y, X), \+m(Y).
holds(i(X)) :- p(X), \+m(X).
holds(f(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), holds(f(Y,X)).
holds(f(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), \+holds(nk(X,Y)).
holds(o(X)) :- p(X), p(Y), holds(t(X,Y)).
holds(o(X)) :- p(X), \+m(X).
holds(nk(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), \+holds(nk(Y,X)).
holds(nk(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), \+holds(f(X,Y)).
holds(t(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), holds(t(Y,X)).
holds(t(X,Y)) :- p(X), p(Y), p(Z), holds(t(X,Z)), holds(t(Z,Y)).
m(X) :- p(X).
```

The answer is suppose to be Bertram, but I kept on getting Arthur. Dont know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that Rules will be far more simpler than that.

For instance, what does mean `m(X) :- p(X).`, given that p(X) is always true ? Does Victor have something to say ?

In logic it's essential to stick to [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). *Programming* logic it's not an exception, albeit the term has a more practical connotation - see [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

I think we can only agree that the murder should be the person that *contradicts* other two. There is only a fact in question: whether or not a person known Victor.

Then what we know about the crime can be summarized:

```
t(a) :- k(b), k(c).
t(b) :- \+ k(b).
t(c) :- k(a), k(b).
k(_).
```

where t(X) stands for `X testimony that`, and k(X) stands for `X known Victor`.
We don't really know about k(X), then we must add k(_).

With that, Prolog can suggest:

```
?- t(X).
X = a ;
X = c.
```

I.e. only a or b can be true.

*EDIT*: because Prolog isn't propositive when it came to negation, here is a way to solicit the solution:

```
m(X) :- member(X, [a,b,c]), \+ t(X).
```

But let's take a more explicit approach:

Instead of clausal form, that leads to immediate availability of Prolog *execution*, as shown above, our fact base could also expressed:

```
say(a, know_victim(b, yes)).
say(a, know_victim(c, yes)).

say(b, know_victim(b, no)).

say(c, know_victim(a, yes)).
say(c, know_victim(b, yes)).
```

now let's see if some some individual says the opposite of others

```
liar(I) :-
    select(I, [a,b,c], Js),
    say(I, Fact),
    maplist(negate(Fact), Js).
negate(know_victim(I, X), J) :-
    say(J, know_victim(I, Y)),
    X \= Y.
```

yields

```
?- liar(I).
I = b ;
false.
```

Comment: But the problem doesnt stated that arthur know victor, is just says arthur is with victor.

Comment: extremely very nice, thank you! I read your `t(X):- G.` predicate as "for the testimony of `X` to be true, `G` must be true.". then we see that `t(b)` is impossible, so Bertrand is necessarily a liar. Of course no court would convict him based solely on that. :) Even if `t(a)` were impossible, we still couldn't conclude that Arthur is a murderer. Yes he is a liar (under that supposition), and he indeed says that he didn't kill Victor the victim, *but* - it is only the *whole* of his testimony that is (would be) false. So again, it wouldn't be enough. :)

Comment: but, I'm having doubts about your proof. You construct this very small closed world, where it is *you* who claims that anyone could have known Victor (`k(_)`), then you use this fact as evidence that it is not impossible to prove that `k(b)`. Seems self-extrication by Munchausen's bootstrapping, to me. :)

Comment: @WillNess: I think the argumentation is justified from the last sentence of the puzzle (Assuming that everyone–except possibly for the murderer–is telling the truth...) It's possible that the question focused on implementing a Prolog meta interpreter for resolution, that works - you know - by contradiction. I.e. it find counterproof to negated literal. But that seems to be overly complicated. To be true, I found that simplicity after pruning some trial, and took a little to understand why it works.

Comment: it works because `\+k(b)` fails, and that is because you've included the fact `k(_)`. This feels a little bit *too* easy. :) That said, I don't know how to approach this problem, myself.

Comment: Without a m(X) :- to something, it doesnt work. I tried "m(X) :- \=t(Y), says(Y,X)." and "m(X) :- \=i(X)." and they both doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Anniepoo/prolog-examples

contains several different ways of solving this.